# Como transformar uma coluna com valores separados por virgula em linhas usando SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Dei uma pesquisada em algumas perguntas do site e não encontrei nada nesse sentido, queria saber se é possível fazer uma consulta `SQL`, em uma coluna `string` onde os valores são separados por virgula. Por exemplo:

```
Tabela usuario
id = int
nome = string
img = string ('https://google.com/img/1, https://google.com/img/2, https://google.com/img/3')
```

o resultado que eu espero seria algo nesse sentido:

```
Tabela resultante da query
id | imgs
1  | 'https://google.com/img/1'  
1  | 'https://google.com/img/2'
1  | 'https://google.com/img/3'
2  | 'https://bing.com/img/1'
2  | 'https://bing.com/img/2'
```

O banco que utilizo é **Microsoft SQL Server** mas gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com **SQL puro**, caso não seja possível uma solução "universal", aceitaria uma resposta para Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Acho que deve procurar por Cross-table

Comment: tem um comando que eu usava pra fazer isso que era o `UNNEST`. Mas creio que não é padrão do sql.

Comment: @Danizavtz `UNNEST` não seria PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE? Ando por fora de de *Transact-SQL*, mas creio que o que o Julio deseja seja o `STRING_SPLIT`, combinado com `CROSS APPLY` para que os dados se relacionem com a própria tabela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for SQL Server 2016 (13.x) ou superior pode user o [**`STRING_SPLIT`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Supondo que originalmente a tabela seja:

| Id | Nome | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C# | desktop,servidor,linha de comando,jogo |
| 2 | PHP | servidor,linha de comando |
| 4 | JavaScript | servidor,navegador,linha de comando |
| 5 | Java | android,servidor,desktop |

Com `STRING_SPLIT` o nome da coluna de saída é `value`, então aplique assim na query:

```
SELECT Id, Nome, value
FROM Tabela
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',');
```

terá um resultado como:

| Id | Nome | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C# | desktop |
| 1 | C# | servidor |
| 1 | C# | linha de comando |
| 1 | C# | jogo |
| 2 | PHP | servidor |
| 2 | PHP | linha de comando |
| 3 | JavaScript | servidor |
| 3 | JavaScript | navegador |
| 3 | JavaScript | linha de comando |
| 4 | Java | android |
| 4 | Java | servidor |
| 4 | Java | desktop |

Exemplo online no [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62a034297a9532e3c5b9718e8529835c)

Comment: Ty, O que seria Tags?

Comment: @JulioHenrique a coluna hipotética que deseja dividir, no seu caso a coluna `img`

Comment: realizei o teste, porem as linhas estão retornando a coluna com o valor integral separado por virgula. tipo 1->php -> servidor, linha de comando. 2->php ->  servidor, linha de comando.

Comment: @JulioHenrique experimente: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=62a034297a9532e3c5b9718e8529835c, ps: editei a resposta, acidentalmente eu tinha removido o `, value` que é o responsável por obter o retorno.

Comment: @JulioHenrique um teste com a sua tabela: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=73785f41fa4984c065f2fb16604adbf5

Comment: Pois é, creio que o problema está na versão do meu Sql, estou testando no microsoft sql server management studio